# Check if there are changes under <path> since <commit-ish>

Tags: git, shell, version-control

Given a `<commit-ish>`, I would like to know if there have been any changes in the repository since that `<commit-ish>` for a particular `<path>`.

Comment: Suppose the file was changed, and then changed back, so that the end result is the same as the original file. Would you want to see that two commits had changed it; or would you want this to be reported as "no change"?

Comment: Also, when you say "any changes since `<commit-ish>`"... can we assume that you have another commitish checked out and only want to see changes reachable from that commitish?  Or do you mean any change reachable from any ref such that `<commit-ish>` is reachable from both the ref and the change?  Or... something else?

Answer (score 1):

`git diff --name-status commit-ish -- path` or `git diff commit-ish -- path`. That should work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `git log --branches=* commit.. -- <file or path`> to list the commit(s) which modify the file/path since the commit you specified.

If it has output, that means the file/path is changes.

Otherwise it has not changed since the certain commit.